# LightOpenID unable to validate MyOpenID

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

For some reason **LightOpenID** fails to validate my **MyOpenID** account.

I've tested the `example.php` that comes along with the library and it works with my **Google** account just fine, but with **MyOpenID** it's always say that the authentication is invalid.

I found that the line causing the failure is the last one in the `validate()` method:

```
743|  return preg_match('/is_valid\s*:\s*true/i', $response);
```

So I guess that some response returns `false` but what kind of response and why could it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered from this same issue. The likely source of the problem is that you are requesting some details such as full name and such data contains non-ASCII characters. In those situations, MyOpenID sends back a post request where such characters get mangled. See this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/issues/detail?id=47) for further details.

As far as I know, it's a bug on MyOpenId's side. The problem is that the MyOpenID service is basically abandoned and the bug will not be fixed. Your alternatives:

- As OpenID user, choose another provider.
- As OpenID consumer, don't request additional data.

Comment: I've tried not to request for any details but I get the same error. On the other hand **openidEnaled** works without any problems.. so I guess the bug is in LightOpenID itself.